# Dynamic import: cannot find module 'antd/lib/locale/zh_CN'

Tags: webpack, babeljs

This error occured after upgrading babel to babel7, and change the preset-env to "modules": "commonjs"

```
    import(`antd/lib/locale/${lang}`).then(module => {
        this.setState({ locale: module.default });
    });
```

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": "commonjs"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "import",
            {
                "libraryName": "antd",
                "style": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "corejs": 2,
                "helpers": false,
                "regenerator": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            false
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
            false
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
            false
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator",
            {
                "proposal": "minimal"
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind"
    ]
}
```

And if I change back to "modules": false, I got another error here:
[image]

For the error2, I found the glob is undefined here in `glob.Raphael`.

I wonder how to solve these errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer here:
`solved it by adding plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]`

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader/issues/68#issuecomment-528788909